# Get image from mysql database using javafx

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I am trying to retrieve images from mysql database using javafx. Images are stored in database using long blob. garbage values appear when doing so . this is the code used to retrieve image from database.

```
JFXTreeTableColumn<Property,String> propertyImage = new JFXTreeTableColumn<>("Image");
propertyImage.setPrefWidth(100); 
propertyImage.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Property, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Property, String> param) {
        return param.getValue().getValue().propertyImage;
    }
});
```

[the property view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bsu2.jpg)

Database connection

```
public class Property extends RecursiveTreeObject<Property>{

     StringProperty propertyId;
     StringProperty address;
     StringProperty state;
     StringProperty zipCode;
     StringProperty price;
     StringProperty bedNum;
     StringProperty bathNum;
     StringProperty propertyImage;
     StringProperty propertyType;
     StringProperty propertyStatus;
     StringProperty squareFeet;
     StringProperty parkingSpot;
     StringProperty agent_id;

     public Property(){
         super();
     }

    public Property(String propertyId, String address, String state, String zipCode, String price, String bedNum, String bathNum, String propertyImage, String propertyType, String propertyStatus, String squareFeet, String parkingSpot, String agent_id) {
        this.propertyId = new SimpleStringProperty(propertyId);
        this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
        this.state = new SimpleStringProperty(state);
        this.zipCode = new SimpleStringProperty(zipCode);
        this.price = new SimpleStringProperty(price);
        this.bedNum = new SimpleStringProperty(bedNum);
        this.bathNum = new SimpleStringProperty(bathNum);
        this.propertyImage = new SimpleStringProperty(propertyImage);
        this.propertyType = new SimpleStringProperty(propertyType);
        this.propertyStatus = new SimpleStringProperty(propertyStatus);
        this.squareFeet = new SimpleStringProperty(squareFeet);
        this.parkingSpot = new SimpleStringProperty(parkingSpot);
        this.agent_id = new SimpleStringProperty(agent_id);
    }

}
```

DB connection

```
ObservableList<Property> properties = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
        Connection connection = DBConnection.getConnection();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement)connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
               properties.add(new Property(rs.getInt(1)+"",rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getString(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getString(9),rs.getString(10),rs.getString(11),rs.getString(12),rs.getString(13)));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SearchSalePropertyController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: *"this is the code used to retrieve image from database."* I fail to see any database access in your code. Also I'm not sure why you use a `String` this property.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, you posted the codes for database access. You are already doing it wrong when you were getting the data from the `ResultSet`.

```
while(rs.next()) {
    InputStream in = new rs.getBinaryStream(8);

    Image image = getImageFromStream(in); // You need to convert this back into a JavaFX Image instance,
                                          // which depends on the original Image, e.g. file format etc.
                                          // It could be as simply as new Image(in) using the JavaFX Image constructor

    properties.add(new Property(
        rs.getInt(1) + "", 
        rs.getString(2),
        rs.getString(3),
        rs.getString(4),
        rs.getString(5),
        rs.getString(6),
        rs.getString(7),
        image,
        rs.getString(9),
        rs.getString(10),
        rs.getString(11),
        rs.getString(12),
        rs.getString(13)
    ));
}
```

Of course, `Property.propertyImage` should also be changed to `ObjectProperty<Image>`. Similarly the column should also be changed to `JFXTreeTableColumn<Property, Image>`.

Comment: I have changed everything from string to image , im having errors in these 2 lines of codes.

Comment: InputStream in = new rs.getBinaryStream(8);

 Image image = getImageFromStream(in);

Comment: You need to do your own conversion - there is no `getImageFromStream()` method. You know your data the best, so you should be the one doing this. If you are not sure, you can *try* `Image image = new Image(in);` for a start.